# How to load a default snippet from a template in sulu?

Tags: sulu

I'm trying to use a snippet to store a contact address meant to be displayed in the footer of every page.

Following the doc (https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.3/cookbook/default-snippets.html), I created a snippet template named `address` in `config/templates/snippets/address.xml` and defined an area in this file, like this :

```
<areas>
    <area key="footer_address">
        <meta>
            <title lang="fr">Adresse dans le pied de page</title>
        </meta>
    </area>
</areas>
```

I created a snippet from this template in the admin area and assigned it in the "Default snippet" tab.

But when I try to load this snippet with `sulu_snippet_load_by_area('footer_address')`. I get the following error :

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("You have requested a non-existent parameter "footer_address".").
```

If I don't assign the snippet from the admin area, the twig function does not throw an error, but return `null`.

I must be doing something wrong, but I can't see what :/

Answer (score 0):

It was just a cache issue. I ran `bin/websiteconsole cache:clear` and it works fine. I was just running `bin/adminconsole cache:clear`, and it was not enough.